# Attempting to pass argument to ioctl call zeros out argument

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, ioctl

I am trying to call an ioctl function in my toy file system module. I would simply like to have this ioctl set a variable that is passed in by the caller. So far I have set up the ioctl infrastructure that has allowed me to make ioctl calls. I have this function in my module to handle ioctl.

```
int ospfs_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp,
      unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    if(cmd == OSPFSIOCRASH)
    {
        eprintk("crash: %ld\n", arg);
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return -ENOTTY;
}
```

And my test function looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#define OSPFSIOCRASH 42

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/tmp/cs111/lab3-thief/test/hello.txt", O_RDWR);
    printf("ioctl call: %d\n", ioctl(fd, OSPFSIOCRASH, 100));
    close(fd);
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
crash: 100
ioctl call: 0
```

but the output is actually

```
crash: 0
ioctl call: 0
```

I bet I'm doing something simple wrong. Could someone please help and point out what the issue is? Thank you kindly.

Comment: What platform are you targeting? x86?

Comment: How do you set up `OSPFSIOCRASH`?  It needs to encode the direction and size of the arguments, probably by using `_IOW(type, nr, unsigned long)`

Comment: It's an x86 emulator (QEMU) running Debian 2.6.18-6-486. If that makes any difference. How do you set up _IOW(type, nr, unsigned long)?

Comment: I suppose I've been lazy implementing ioctl. I copied the supporting infrastructure from another person's code. In total there is a hook into the kernal `.ioctl = ospfs_ioctl` there is a constant cmd number defined in the module header `OSPFSIOCRASH` and there is an ioctl handling function (above). That's all the ioctl code the other project has. I'm just noticing that the other project doesn't pass any arguments in using ioctl... I'm not really sure what I need to make that work.

Comment: The test program *really* ought to examine the result of `open()`.  I don't know how many needless headaches I have had because the filesystem did not remount correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the solution which solves your problem, but based on the limited information from your question and the comments, this what I could gather.

Based on the question and the comments, it looks like you have defined a `struct file_operations` structure in this fashion:

```
struct file_operations fops = { .ioctl=ospfs_ioctl };
```

And the signature of your `ospfs_ioctl` suggests that you're using the older ioctl.

With the recent kernels (at least after 2.6.35+ or something), it is recommended to use `.unlocked_ioctl` instead of `.ioctl`.

```
struct file_operations fops = { .unlocked_ioctl=ospfs_ioctl };
```

And the definition of the `ospfs_ioctl` function would change to:

```
long ospfs_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
```

The differences between `unlocked_ioctl` and the regular ioctl can be found [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/119652/). In short it does not take the dreaded `BKL` before invoking the ioctl.

And also as per `Chris Dodd`'s suggestion, you should double check how you're defining your `OSPFIOCRASH`. The recommended way is to make use of the `_IO(magic, some_num_for_ioctl)`

Comment: Hey tuxdude, that's interesting I may try to change to `.unlocked_ioctl` later. For now I've gotten ioctl to work thanks to some comment suggestions. My fix is in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As per Chris Dodd's suggestion I changed `#define OSPFIOCRASH 42` to `#define OSPFSIOCRASH _IO(magic, 0)` and have since gotten the desired behavior.